# check Palindrome

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

why it throws exceptions in the main when I try to use this method?
I doubt that there is something wrong with the return statements

```
public static boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {
    String [] letters=inputString.split("");
    int num=inputString.length();
    int middle=num%2;
    boolean plaindrome=false;
    if(middle==0){
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
            if(letters[i].equals(letters[num-i])){// it tells there is something wrong on this line
                plaindrome= true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
            if(letters[i].equals(letters[num-i])){
                plaindrome= true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return plaindrome;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: The problem is that when `i=0`, you are accessing `letters[num]` and arrays start at 0. Also, not related, but you can use `inputString.charAt(i)` instead of splitting.

Comment: Change the `letters[num-i]` to `letters[num-i-1]`, you could also use `char[] letters = inputString.toCharArray();` and then use `==` instead of `.equals` - also, why have `palindrome` the variable? If you reach the final return it must be `true`. Finally, you only need to check the first half of the characters.... once you pass that point you are "double" checking.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.